# Can a C++ lambda member function access member variables?

Tags: c++, lambda

I am looking for a way for a lambda member function to access member variables. For example:

Given a simple class:

```
#include <functional>

class MyClass {
public:
  MyClass(function<void()> myFunc);
  int myData = 555;
}
```

And then when instantiating I can access a class member like so:

```
MyClass a([](){ std::cout << a.myData; });
```

But I need to change how I access the data every time I use this e.g.:

```
MyClass b([](){ std::cout << b.myData; });
```

Ideally I could capture the member and use it like so:

```
MyClass a([myData](){ std::cout << myData; });
```

Thank you!

Comment: You have to capture a.myData. Being an argument to the constructor doesn't give the lambda access to the object. Overall that code doesn't make much sense. Maybe describe what you actually want to do and not a meaningless toy problem.

Comment: You say that `MyClass a([](){ std::cout << a.myData; });` works, but it doesn't. You need to capture `a` for it to work: `MyClass a([&a] { std::cout << a.myData; });`

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could define your constructor like this:

```
MyClass(function<void(MyClass*)> myFunc) {
   myFunc(this);
}
```

You don't necessarily have to invoke `myFunc` in your constructor, you could stash it as a member variable.

Then define something like this:

```
auto fn = [](MyClass* ptr) {
    cout << ptr->myData;
}
```

So you can invoke constructors like this:

```
MyClass b(fn);
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
struct MyClass {
  MyClass(function<void(int&)> func);
};
```

And you call it with the member variable as the argument. Or, if you need to access many fields, you may change it to `function<void(MyClass&)>` and call it with `*this` as the argument.